# How can I get the props values in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'd like to get prop values in Vue.js, because i need to receive **eid** in my component to do verification, but i don't know how can i do this and if i do **this.configs.eid** is **undefined**. Another way is send **data()** value from my **component A** to **component B**.

I have this component and i need to get **eid** then insert in **v-if**

```html
<section v-if="" >
  <stream  :configs="{eid : event.id}"></stream>
</section>
```

Another way is send this **data()** from **component A** to **component B**

```js
data() {
  return {
    tipo: String,
    link: String,
    eid : 0
  };
}
```

In **component A** my props is

```
props: {
    configs: {
      type: Object
    }
  },
```

I don't know how to get it, anybody knows? :/

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking. Are you wanting to get the `eid` value within your `<stream>` component?

Comment: @Phil i need to get **eid** , because it save my **event_id** then I need to compare in **v-if** to show my component **<stream>**

Comment: I suggest reading the documentation https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props

You must define a `props` section in your component. Then all of your `props` are available. In the template, they're just available as their name - for example - `configs`. If you're between the `<script>` tags, `configs` will be available in `this` like: `this.configs.eid`.

Comment: Sorry, it's still very unclear. Could you please provide a better overview of your application. What components do you have? What data do they store or provide and where are you trying to get access to that data?

Comment: @nucleogenesis  my prop config is in component A `props: {
    configs: {
      type: Object
    }
  },  ` I need to get **eid** in component B

Comment: the problem is get **eid** value :/

Comment: Why don't you put `event.id` into `v-if`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear, there is no definition which component is A and which is B.

It seems that you may have mixed up parent & child, so I'll just try to show how to pass eid both ways.

If you want to pass eid from the child stream component to the parent for v-if check (which I think is the case), you need to use $emit, not prop:

Component A (Parent)

```
<section v-if="event.id == 0">
    <stream @get-event-id="getEventId"></stream>
</section>

data() {
    configs: {
        event: {}
    }
},
methods: {
    getEventId(id) {
        this.configs.event.id = id
    }
}
```

Component B (Child)

```
data() {
    event: {id: 0}
},
mounted(){
    this.$emit('get-event-id', this.event.id)
},
```

That way if stream eid will be 0, like here, the component will not render.

However, if you would need to pass eid from parent component to stream component, it would look like this:

Component A (Parent)

```
<section v-if="">
    <stream :configs="{eid : event.id}"></stream>
</section>

data() {
    event: {id: 0}
}
```

Component B (Child)

```
props: ['configs'],
mounted(){
    console.log(this.configs.eid)
},
```

This way you will get in console the parent's eid.

Comment: FYI, Vue very strongly recommends using kebab-case for all custom event names, eg instead of `@getEventId`, use `@get-event-id` and `$emit('get-event-id', this.event.id)`. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names

Comment: @Phil, indeed! Thank you for information! Changed the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to send the `event.id` to stream as property, then you can simply do it like this

```
<section v-if="" >
  <stream  :eventId="event.id"></stream>
</section>
```

Then from the `Stream.vue` component, you can receive the property like

```
export default {
    name: "Stream",
    props: ["eventId"]
}
```